# Check e-mail from other accounts with Gmail using Google Apps for Work

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

With free Gmail, you can add up to five other e-mail accounts to check from Gmail via POP3. How many e-mail accounts can you add to Gmail using *Google Apps for Work*?

Comment: The same number.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Sure;  The Google support article which mentions the 5 account limit.

Comment: But that article doesn't refer to Google Apps for Work, does it?

Comment: @Ramhound: Ae you sure, anyway, that the limitation is the same using Google Apps for Work?